# Adding Boost Library to a C++ project in Windows Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I recently installed the Boost Library on Windows using the installer, I'm trying to link to the library in Eclipse but am not having any luck.  I tried going through Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries and add the reference "boost_filesystem" according to this website: http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//archive/DOMM-76JN6N , but I think that only applies to Unix variants.  Everytime I compile I get the error: "cannot find -lboost_filesystem" .  I've scoured the net, but cannot find a way to properly use Boost in Eclipse under a Windows platform.  Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It doesn't matter what IDE you use. The fact that the code was written in eclipse is immaterial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Eclipse for Visual Studio C++ Developers ( also has explanations for boost library) )](http://elangovv.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/using-boost-library-in-eclipse-cdt-with-cygwin-and-mingw/)  is what you needed..

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the MinGW (GCC) Compiler Suite in `c:\mingw`. Eclipse will detect the toolchain, that includes the boost library.