# Problem with basic program using Boost Threads in c++

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

I have a simple program which creates and executes as thread using boost threads in c++.

```
#include<boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include<iostream>


void hello()
{

    std::cout<<"Hello, i am a thread"<<std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    boost::thread th1(&hello);
    th1.join();


}
```

The compiler throws an error against the th1.join() line. It says 
"
         Multiple markers at this line

```
- undefined reference to 

 `boost::thread::join()'

- undefined reference to 

 `boost::thread::~thread()'
```

"

Comment: Are the boost headers in your compiler's include path? Are you linking to any necessary libraries?

Comment: I guess I am, not sure though..

Comment: That is a link error. You are probably not passing the required library (concrete option will depend on your library version, platform and other things) to the linker.

Comment: try adding `-lboost_thread` or `-lboost_thread-mt`

Comment: I am using the Eclipse IDE... I am not sure , where I need to add those...

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the problem of not including appropriate headers / linking libs.

1) You should check your include path for having appropriate `boost` folder and boost headers.
2) You should build your application with appropriate static libraries (`xxx.lib`) files. For boost::thread that file would be named something like `libboost_thread_xxx.lib`

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, right-click on your project and go to Properties.

Goto C/C++ Build -> settings -> tool settings

Next, open the Libraries section under GCC C++ Linker.

In the Libraries (-l) panel add an entry with the value `boost_thread`.

(I'm assuming your using Linux, if not  check out [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336211/adding-boost-library-to-a-c-project-in-windows-eclipse))

Comment: Thanks, but I am using a windows machine. I tried doing the dame for windows and it cannot link correctly to the file. I am trying to read the entire article pointed out by your link but it seems too verbose..

Comment: how did you install boost then? did you build it from source?